# Show changes in git when branch is shown as commit id

Tags: git

I made a lot of changes (which I should have committed more frequently, I know), and at some point the branch was showing as `@372ee52`, now I cannot see any changes as if they were never made.

[image]

Is there a way to get those changes? I tried using IntelliJ's local history, but there are way too many changes missing.

I've searched all the commits to find the one with that ID, there is none.

thank you.

EDIT:
to clarify: I committed the changes not realizing the active branch was not `main`, then I tried to push, but it failed. After that I can only see the `main` branch.

git log shows my older commits but non of those contain the changes I made.

git status shows only the changes I tried to get when using IntelliJ's local history feature.

git branch shows only the main branch.

Comment: In order to clarify your issue, give the ouput of these commands: `git status`, `git log`, `git branch`.

Comment: And also `git reflog -20` (that shows the most recent 20 lines of `git reflog`), which I suspect is going to be the most useful given your description of the problem.

Comment: I see the commit id on the list!! it looks like this: 372ee52 HEAD@{5}: commit: my message

Comment: You are in detached head state. At some point you did a checkout of a commit and not a branch. Create a branch where you are now, commit and push that

Comment: right now I'm in the main branch and I don't know how to get that particular commit into my main branch

Comment: You are not on the main branch - you are in a detached head state. That `git branch` shows the main branch does not mean that's the currently used branch.

Comment: If you want the commit on the `main` branch, switch to `main` and cherry-pick the commits you want from your reflog. If you want multiple commits in a row that are all reachable from a single commit, you can also cherry-pick a range, or use rebase with the `--onto` flag. For sanity purposes, if you have just a few commits, cherry-pick them individually so you don't have to learn the other syntax when you're sweating.

Comment: the reflog option helped me to see the commit and then I did a checkout to that id, created a new branch with the commits in that detached state. After that I merged my changes to my main branch. Lesson learned!
@larsks, please put your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you made some commits when you were in a "detached head" state. The commits were recorded, but they're not associated with any branch. The `git reflog` command will show you how the value of `HEAD` has changed over time in your local repository; this gives you a history of branch changes, new commits, etc.

Look at the last several entries show by `git reflog` and you will probably see the commits you made before switch to the `main` branch.

You can create a new branch pointing at the most recent commit in that series by running `git branch <branchname> <commit id>`.